# First order dedekind completeness

Tags: real-analysis, first-order-logic

According to [1], $\mathbb{R}$ is unique (up to isomorphism) "due" to its
archimedian property. According to [2], said property is not firstorderizable.

This second statement makes sense on its own, when elements of the universe of
discourse are real numbers, not sets of them. But to be able to speak about isomorphisms between different Dedekind-complete ordered fields one has to embed them into a larger
theory. Why cannot this theory be a first order theory? ZFC can express the
subset property, so where is the problem with [2]'s axiom 4?

- [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach
- [2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#On_the_least_upper_bound_property

Comment: That just pushes the issue to a higher level. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that there is a unique-up-to-isomorphism Dedekind-complete ordered field, but $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself has "disagreeing models" - we can have $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ whose versions of the reals $\mathbb{R}^\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathbb{R}^\mathcal{N}$ are not isomorphic ("in reality," or if you prefer "in some $\mathcal{A}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}\in\mathcal{A}$").

Comment: Is $ZFC_1$ at fault? Is it not possible to have an ambient (level 0) $ZFC_2$ theory which has two $ZFC_2$ models (level 1) whose level-2-unique $\mathbb{R}$'s are nonisomorphic "on level 0"?

Answer (score 0):

The language used for the axiomatization uses the (non-logical) symbols $\langle +,\cdot,0,1,\le\rangle$ where $+,\cdot$ are binary functions, $0,1$ are $0$-ary functions and $\le$ is a binary relation.

The Dedekind completeness axiom states
$$\forall U(((\exists x Ux)\land(\exists x\forall y(Uy\rightarrow y\le x)))\rightarrow(\exists x((\forall y Uy\rightarrow y\le x)\land(\forall z((\forall y Uy\rightarrow y\le z)\rightarrow x\le z)))))\quad (1)$$

Which is a second-order statement with $U$ quantifying over unary relations.

Call the other axioms $\Gamma$.  The statements in $\Gamma$ are all first-order statements in the language $\langle +,\cdot,0,1,\le\rangle$.

What they're saying is that there is no first-order statement $(1')$ in the language $\langle +,\cdot,0,1,\le\rangle$ such that $\Gamma\cup\{(1)\}$ has the same models as $\Gamma\cup\{(1')\}$.

This follows from the Lowenheim-Skolem theorems, because a first-order theory cannot have a single infinite model unique up to isomorphism.  On the other hand, the second-order theory $\Gamma\cup\{(1)\}$ (where $(1)$ is the only second-order statement and it merely quantifies over a single unary relation) has a unique model up to isomorphism.

Comment: I can accept that we need second order logic to get a unique $\mathbb{R}$. But how does this refute firstorderizability? If two first order models of $\mathbb{R}$ have their own Dedekind completeness, it is still firstorderized, no? The theory of "there exist at most three things" is firstorderizable and has nonisomorphic models.

Comment: @Damian:  The *definition* of 'firstorderizability' is that $(1)$ is replaced by a set $\Delta$ of first-order sentences in the same language such that $\Gamma\cup\{(1)\}$ has the same models as $\Gamma\cup\Delta$.  But $\Gamma\cup\{(1)\}$ has just one model $\Bbb{R}$ (up to isomorphism).  If $\Bbb{R}$ is a model of $\Gamma\cup\Delta$ then $\Gamma\cup\Delta$ has models of all infinite cardinalities.

Comment: Ok, Wikipedia's definition is the "inability of a natural-language statement to be adequately captured by a formula of first-order logic". Second order logic is only mentioned anecdotally.

Comment: @Damian: "Specifically, a statement is nonfirstorderizable if there is no formula of first-order logic which is true in a model if and only if the statement holds in that model."  There is no statement of first-order logic that is true in a model if and only if $(1)$ is true in a model - because any statement of first-order logic that is true in $\Bbb{R}$ is also true in models in which $(1)$ is false.

Comment: `(1)` is your statement, not the statement from [2] axiom 4.

Comment: Moreover, [2] does not present uniqueness as a defining property, so `(1)` is a sufficient but not necessary instantiation of [2]'s axiom 4.